# Do power armor mods drain the Fusion Core faster?

Tags: fallout-4

The Jet Pack mod obviously increases power consumption while in use because a loading screen tip specifically mentions that fact.

What about other mods like Tesla coils, targeting HUD, or RAD scrubbers? Do they increase the rate of power consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Fusion Cores are drained by using Action Points. If your armor mod does not use action points then the mod will not increase your rate of power consumption.

This means that the jet pack will increase power drain when used since it uses action points, while the mod to reduce action points used while sprinting will reduce power consumption.

Comment: But Fusion Cores aren't _only_ drained by using Action Points because doing nothing but just walking around will drain them. Are you sure that mods which don't specifically use AP don't increase the passive drain?

Comment: The only modification to the power drain is the perks/Repair Bobblehead.  Those only state that fusion cores last X% longer.  For fusion core drains, there's a movement drain, AP Usage (includes sprinting), and the jetpack (only mod that drains the core, maybe because of AP usage?).  I would need to open up the ESM file to see if there are any other drains for power armor.  If i do, i will let you know.